# Notify player when they are eliminated from GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: ios, ios5, game-center

I'm writing a turn based game in which a player can be eliminated by another player.  When this happens I'd like to notify the player who's been eliminated that they have lost the game.  I'm setting the MatchOutcome on the player, but it seems like the notification isn't sent to the player until the match as a whole is over.

Is there a way to do this with the game center APIs, or would I have to implement my own push notifications on top of GameCenters notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution, given a game between players A, B, C and D and an alphabetical play order:
Player A kills player C. At the end of the turn, play passes to the dead player (player C).
Player C is notified of their turn and discovers that they have been eliminated. The game automatically removes them from the match and passes play to player B (as B should have been next to act after A).
After player B's turn, play passes to player D and the game continues as normal.